# Como mostrar dados no template

Tags: aplicação-web, django

Tenho este model:

```
class template(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

está view:

```
def home(request):
    dados = template.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html', {'dados':dados})
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="pt-br">


    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> {{ template.nome }} </title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
      <meta content="" name="keywords">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">  <!-- Favicons -->
      <link href="{% static 'img/favicon.png' %}" rel="icon">
      <link href="{% static 'img/apple-touch-icon.png' %}" rel="apple-touch-icon">

      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Philosopher:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Bootstrap css -->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> -->
      <link href="{% static 'lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet' %}">

      <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
      <link href="{% static 'lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'lib/animate/animate.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'lib/modal-video/css/modal-video.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
      <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
```

E estou chamando o atribibuto no template assim: {{ template.nome }}

Minha intenção é criar um formulario para que o usuario pode editar dados no template (ex: nome da empresa, contatos, slogan), estou usando django admin para o formulario porém não aparece nada no template, alguém pode me apontar o erro? esta é a forma correta de se fazer?

Comment: Da para vc colocar o codigo da sua template?

Comment: Pronto coloquei.

Comment: Ok, mas onde vc esta mostrando os dados na template? Não entendi o que vc quer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu exemplo vc não está tratando os dados que foram enviados para a template, baseado no seu codigo vou criar um exemplo, só que, para simplificar, meus dados serão "hardcoded" ao invés de virem de uma queryset:

Arquivo view.py

```
def home(request):
    dados = dict(Nome = 'Danilo Costa', Fone='123456')
    return render(request,'index.html', dados)
```

Digamos que na template vc queira apresentar o nome e o endereço envidados através do dicionário `dados`:

Arquivo index.html

```
<p>
    O Nome enviado foi {{dado.nome}}<br>
    O endereço enviado foi {{dado.endereço}}
</p>
```